# Select dates based in certain criteria in a dataframe

Tags: r, datetime, filter, dplyr

I have a dataframe comprised by 4 columns, with temperature data from 3 different locations, from different periods *rbind*-ed in   a single data frame. I want to select *temperatures* which are in common dates/time(hours)  from the 3 stations.

Below I provide a reproducible example :

```
a1 <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("1995-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2007-04-01"), by = "120 min")
a2 <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("1998-04-19"), as.POSIXct("2004-03-20"), by = "60 min")
a3 <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("1991-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2001-04-01"), by = "180 min")


t1 <- runif(length(a1), min = -5, max = 45)
t2 <- runif(length(a2), min = -5, max = 45)
t3 <- runif(length(a3), min = -5, max = 45)


station1 <- data.frame(date = a1, temp = t1, ID = "station1")
station2 <- data.frame(date = a2, temp = t2, ID = "station2")
station3 <- data.frame(date = a3, temp = t3, ID = "station3")

all_stat <- rbind(station1,station2,station3)


all_stat <- all_stat %>%
  mutate(time = hms::as_hms(date),
         date = as_date(date)) %>%
  relocate(date, time)
```

Idealy I would like to have the four columns data frame (date/time/temp/ID) with **only** the common dates/hours of temp data, among these 3 stations. I tried multiple things with `dplyr` as well as `subset` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in `tidyverse`.

```
library(dplyr)   
library(stringr)
all_stat %>%       
    group_by(datetime = str_c(date, time)) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(ID) == n_distinct(all_stat$ID))
```

---

Or if we want to make this faster, use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(all_stat)[, datetime := paste(date, time)]
sub_stat <- all_stat[all_stat[, .I[uniqueN(ID) == uniqueN(all_stat$ID)],
             by = datetime]$V1]
```

Comment: Dear @akrun, in the example here your solution works perfectly but when I applied it to my real data I got the following message: 
Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` column `datetime`.
i `datetime = str_c(date, time) %>% filter(Df_All_stat(ID) == n_distinct(Df_All_stat$ID))`.
x no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @H.Johnson I think my line is `filter(n_distinct(ID) == n_distinct(all_stat$ID))` and not `filter(Df_All_stat(ID) == n_distinct(Df_All_stat$ID))`

Comment: @H.Johnson you are applying the object name as a function `Df_All_stat(`

Comment: @H.Johnson I would appreicate if you clarify that part.  thanks

Comment: Yes you are right @akrun, It was my mistake replacing variable's name to function. Right now I am running the script you gave me in my real data and I will provide feedback!

Comment: it worked! The only disadvantage of dplyr selection is that it need approximately 4 minutes to complete the script-run. Nevertheless dplyr is the easiest and more practical way to run these kind of selections, therefore I conclude that your solution is the best one.   e.g. In order the date,time column be more properly displayed it needs to be written as:    '' str_c(date, time,sep = " ") ''

Comment: @H.Johnson you can make it faster with `data.table`

Comment: @H.Johnson can you try with datat.able update.  I would assume it to be faster

Comment: Yes, it is much faster, although I'll stick with the dplyr solution as it is much easier! Thank you very much for your time and effort to help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Combine `date` and `time` to create datetime column. `split` the `datetime` variable for each `ID` and find the common ones using `Reduce` and use it to subset the dataframes to keep only the common date and times between all the `ID`'s.

```
all_stat$datetime <- paste(all_stat$date, all_stat$time)
result <- subset(all_stat, datetime %in% 
                    Reduce(intersect, split(all_stat$datetime, all_stat$ID)))
```

Comment: works perfectly! Thank you for being so analytical in your explanation!